# Rails FactoryGirl instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I would like to create factory using local variable.
Currently I have the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :offer_item, class: BackOffice::OfferItem do
    service
    variant
  end
end
```

My expectation is to create something like below

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
    variant = FactroyGirl.create(:variant)
    factory :offer_item, class: BackOffice::OfferItem do
      service
      variant { variant }

      after(:create) do |offer_item|
        offer_item.service.variants << variant
      end
    end
  end
```

but then I get:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find': Factory not registered: variant (ArgumentError)
```

All models are nested inside `BackOffice` module. Generally I want the same object has association with two other objects. I think there is a some problem with scope in my factory.

Variant factory is inside other separated file.

Comment: do you have gem 'factory_girl_rails' in your gemfile?

Comment: Of course I do.  gem 'factory_girl_rails'

Comment: Nowhere do I see you define `factory :variant` -- This is why it's saying `Factory not registered`

Comment: It is inside other file. All my factories are nested inside `back_office` directory

Comment: @mike927 If it's not in your question, it doesn't exist

Comment: @WesFoster what do you mean?

Comment: what he means is you MUST provide full context in your question. By not including the definition of that factory you have basically failed to let us know about it and answer your question with it in mind. By excluding it you've told us that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to create a factory before FactoryGirl has finished loading all of the factory definitions. This is because you defined the variable at the scope of a factory definition. Even if this did work, you would likely end up sharing the same variant record between multiple `offer_items` that you create in your test because this code would only get executed once during initialization.

Since you defined an association to `Variant`, you probably don't need to create it as an extra step. We can leverage FactoryGirl's ability to create our associations for us and then copy the object into your `#service` in your `after(:create)` callback. Maybe it would look something like this (untested):

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :offer_item, class: BackOffice::OfferItem do
    service
    variant

    after(:create) do |offer_item|
      offer_item.service.variants << offer_item.variant
    end
  end
end
```